# Read/process .fit files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, gpx, garmin

I need to read and parse .fit files (used e.g. by Garmin devices, see [fit sdk](http://www.thisisant.com/resources/fit), a binary alternative to the GPX-file format) in the browser on the client side using Javascript (and e.g. FileReader). I am aware of (and have tried) [Python](https://github.com/dtcooper/python-fitparse) and [Perl](http://pub.ks-and-ks.ne.jp/cycling/GarminFIT.shtml) implementations, but I have not been able to find any code in Javascript.

Alternatively I could work with a PHP on the server side, but client-side parsing for the case when there is not internet connection would be ideal.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: PHP server-side .fit file reader: https://github.com/adriangibbons/php-FIT-File-Reader

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old post but there are now at least two npm packages for this:

- [fit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fit)
- [easy-fit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-fit)

My recommendation would be easy-fit, as the fit project no longer seems to be active, and relies on java bindings which don't seem to work out of the box with Node 4.1.